# Reduce Spring & Hibernate initialization time while executing JUnit test cases

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, automated-tests, junit5

we're using a Spring/Hibernate application and JUnit to execute tests (using IntelliJ). When I have to develop/execute a test, the application startup time is about 10-30 seconds, depending on the number of Hibernate entities to be initialized.

I'm wondering if there is any solution to minimize the initialization time. My idea is to basically have an application server instance where the initialized application is running and I'm able to execute JUnit tests on this application without having to build the Spring/Hibernate context after one test has been finished, but instead to reexecute it immediately after adapting the code.

So my question is if there is a feasible approach and any thoughts/feedback is greatly appreciated. For simplification, let's assume that only test code is going to be changed, not any production code as this probably would require hotswapping or any similar mechanism.

Best regards,
Niko

Comment: I was facing the same problem. I switch real db to memory db for repository test, used @DataJpaTest  annotation and use Mock for service layer. So, spring was not loading all the beans. It improved a lot for my case.

Comment: This might be a feasible approach for unit tests, but proved rather difficult with integration tests. In our case, it is more Hibernate that takes so long to bootstrap and in the persistence layer, it can be very difficult to isolate what required to load and what can be dropped. Plus, this is only for local testing as a CI tool like Jenkins only bootstraps once, so in that context, it is not a big deal to load the whole application. My goal is to not touch legacy code and production code and to explore other possibilities.